# What is the most efficient way to get count of records in Cosmos query?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am writing a `SQL` query in `Cosmos` where I noticed that getting `COUNT` is very expensive. This is most likely the way I have written my query.

i.e., my criteria are, get count of all ids where item (array) is not empty and it either contains vendor name `Amazon` or `Ebay` and has updatedDateTime or createdDateTime prior to some date.

```
SELECT COUNT(c.id) AS totalCount 
FROM c 
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(c.items) > 0 
AND EXISTS (SELECT VALUE l FROM l IN c.items WHERE (CONTAINS (l.vendor, 'Amazon', true) OR CONTAINS (l.vendor, 'Ebay', true) ) 
AND ((IS_DEFINED(l.updatedDateTime) AND l.updatedDateTime >= '2023-09-01') OR c.createdDateTime >= '2023-09-01'))
```

This gives me the desired result, but I see `2237.38 RUs` which I want to reduce as much as possible.

How to make this more efficient?